# beautifulsoup - how to find tags starting with certain attribute?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

For example, I have:

```
<a class="banana" href="http://example.com">link1</a>
<a href="http://example2.com" class="banana"><img ... /></a>
<a class="banana">link2</a>
<a href="http://google.com">link3</a>
```

How I can get:

```
['<a href="http://example2.com" class="banana"><img ... /></a>','<a href="http://google.com">link3</a>']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css selector `a[href]` to get `a` tags with `href` attribute:

```
h = '''
<a class="banana" href="http://example.com">link1</a>
<a href="http://example2.com" class="banana"><img ... /></a>
<a class="banana">link2</a>
<a href="http://google.com">link3</a>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
print(soup.select('a[href]'))
```

output:

```
[<a class="banana" href="http://example.com">link1</a>,
 <a class="banana" href="http://example2.com"><img ...=""/></a>,
 <a href="http://google.com">link3</a>]
```

Comment: But I need only those tags that starting with attribute "href", i.e. `<a href="http://example2.com" class="banana"><img ... /></a>` and `<a href="http://google.com">link3</a>`?

Comment: @jazzis18, BeautifulSoup (and other html parser) normally does not distinguish the order of attributes.

Comment: I see... So I have list of tags "a" and items type not string... Then how I can get this tags that starting with "href"?

Comment: @jazzis18, It seems like you repeat same question, or I misunderstood.

Comment: @jazzis18, Do you want this? `print([str(x) for x in soup.select('a[href]')])`

Comment: Yeah, I did so. Thx :) Only I got: `[elem for elem in soup.findAll('a') if str(elem).startswith('<a href')]`

Comment: @jazzis18, That could produce what you don't want because BeautifulSoup mangle the order of the attributes.

Comment: @jazzis18, For example, using the list comprehension, I only get `[<a href="http://google.com">link3</a>]` for the given html.

Comment: Using your list comprehension or my one?